# Django settings secret key environment variable 502 nginx

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I have a Django webapp running on an Ubuntu server using nginx and gunicorn. I'm trying to get my `settings.py` set up properly in regards to using environment variables to hide secret information such as the `SECRET_KEY` as well as API keys.

I've tried putting `export SECRET_KEY='secret_key'` in `.bashrc` as well as `.profile`, and using `SECRET_KEY=os.environ['SECRET_KEY']` in my `settings.py` file, but this throws a 502 bad gateway error with nginx and its version at the bottom, upon restarting gunicorn. I'm not sure what else to try, as I'm pretty new to setting up servers.

I *believe* this is the init file for my gunicorn service:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=myuser
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/myuser/myproject/mysite
ExecStart=/home/myuser/myproject/mysite/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/myuser/myproject/mysite/mysite.sock mysite.wsgi:application


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I found this error in the nginx error log when trying to request the site, where it gives the 502 bad gateway:

```
*20 connect() to unix:/home/myuser/myproject/mysite/mysite.sock failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

Comment: Whose .bashrc are you using? What user are you running gunicorn as? How are you starting gunicorn?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm using the .bashrc located in my user folder, this user I'm also using to run gunicorn (which is inside a virtualenv folder in my project). I'm not sure the exact method I'm using to start gunicorn, I'm simply using "service gunicorn restart" in order to apply changes to the server.

Comment: Since you are using `service` to start gunicorn, that means you are running it under upstart. You should post the init script you are using.

Comment: Where is this file typically located?

Comment: Well it's in /etc/init/, but *you* must have put it there, it doesn't exist on its own.

Comment: I followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04) guide to get the server up and running. I still have a lot to learn as this is an entirely new world away from actually developing the project. I didn't see anything in there mentioning upstart, however I do believe I'm using systemd if that is of any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this issue by putting my environment variables within the `gunicorn.service` file, located in `/etc/systemd/system/`, as `export` works only in the current shell.

Env variables were input in the file as the following format:

```
[Service]
Environment="SECRET_KEY=secret-key-string"
```